# Why is my accuracy high from the beginning of training?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am training a neural network to recognize some of attributes on .png pictures, and what I get when I start training is something like this, and it is increasing till the end of the epoch:

```python
32/4817 [..............................] - ETA: 167s - loss: 0.6756 - acc: 0.5
64/4817 [..............................] - ETA: 152s - loss: 0.6214 - acc: 0.7  
96/4817 [..............................] - ETA: 145s - loss: 0.6169 - acc: 0.7 
128/4817 [.............................] - ETA: 142s - loss: 0.5972 - acc: 0.7 
160/4817 [.............................] - ETA: 140s - loss: 0.5734 - acc: 0.7 
192/4817 [>............................] - ETA: 138s - loss: 0.5604 - acc: 0.7 
224/4817 [>............................] - ETA: 137s - loss: 0.5427 - acc: 0.7 
256/4817 [>............................] - ETA: 135s - loss: 0.5160 - acc: 0.7 
288/4817 [>............................] - ETA: 134s - loss: 0.5492 - acc: 0.7 
320/4817 [>............................] - ETA: 133s - loss: 0.5574 - acc: 0.7 
352/4817 [=>...........................] - ETA: 131s - loss: 0.5559 - acc: 0.7 
384/4817 [=>...........................] - ETA: 129s - loss: 0.5550 - acc: 0.7 
416/4817 [=>...........................] - ETA: 128s - loss: 0.5504 - acc: 0.7 
448/4817 [=>...........................] - ETA: 127s - loss: 0.5417 - acc: 0.7 
480/4817 [=>...........................] - ETA: 126s - loss: 0.5425 - acc: 0.7
```

My question is why is the starting accuracy so high? I suppose it should be something around 0.1 and then increasing while learning.

Also, at the end I get:

```python
('Test loss:', 0.42451223436727564)
('Test accuracy:', 0.82572614112830256)
```

Is that too big test loss?

This is my network:

```python
input_shape = x_train[0].shape
print(input_shape)
model = Sequential()

stoplearn = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, 
patience=0, verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[stoplearn])
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

It is written in Python using Keras.

Comment: Are you doing a binary classification task? Is your data set balanced?

Comment: Have you tried to initialize your seed to reproduce your output?

Answer (score 5):

You classify your data into two classes (since your output layer is of size 2), so accuracy of 0.5 is not high. In fact, it means that your network behaves randomly, which is what you expect at the beginning. Regarding the loss, there is no absolute answer for that. Your test accuracy seems not bad, and you could try to play with some of the parameters (for example, taking smaller size for the fully connected layer) to see whether you can improve it.

Comment: "In fact, it means that your network behaves randomly, which is what you expect at the beginning" - While it is probably true, you can't conclude that. In a task which I can perfectly solve, I can also give you answers which lead to 50% accuracy.

Comment: @MartinThoma A perfect solution (aka model) would result in 100% accuracy rather than 50%. I consider Miriam´s argument as correct.

Comment: @petezurich My example might be bad. I was talking about an adult human who gets e.g. basic arithmetic questions. The human can give any accuracy he wants, as he knows what is correct. Let's give a probably better example: Assume you have a feature in your training set which is equal to the class. It makes perfect sense that the model learns to use only that feature. So the model does NOT behave randomly. But this feature is only correct in 50% of the cases in the test set. Hence you have 50% accuracy AND a network with does NOT behave randomly.

Comment: @Martin Thomas Thanks for the clarification! I see Miriam's argument still standing, since the model randomly chose one side (aka one class) that it always predict. It then does indeed stick non-randomly to this choice and achieves 50% accuracy as you in turn correctly pointed out. I just wanted to make sure that OP understands that the model still hasn't learned anything useful...

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes. Random choice will lead to 50% accuracy. This is what you get in the beginning. Hence your result is expected.

The reason why it jumps directly to 70% accuracy could be that your problem is simple.

If you want to double-check it, you could

1. use other classifiers,
2. check how many examples are used to calculate accuracy,
3. serialize the trained classifier and manually feed it with new examples and check their results